# Yii2 Arraydataprovider custom value

Tags: php, yii2, dataprovider

First of all, I'm really disappointed after all googling and getting nothing!

I have an Arraydataprovider called

```
$data = [
    400 => [
        'name' => 'x',
        'lesson_1' => '10',
        'lesson_2' => '9',
        ...
    ],
    389 => ...
]
```

It's generated in a for loop.

I want the values to be shown in a text box :

```
foreach($lessons as $lid => $name) {
        $attrs[] = [
                'attribute' => 'lesson_' . $lid,
                'label' => $name['name'], 
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function($model, $key, $index) use($lid, &$data) {
                        return '<input class="txt" data-lid="'.$lid.'" type="text" value="'.$data[$key]['lesson_'.$lid].'"/>';
                }

        ];
}
```

It gives me error : **Undefined index: lesson_49**
But I'm sure that $data provider, has the key lesson_49 (proved by var_dump);

what is the problem? :-(

Comment: maybe try to use `var_dump($data)` in your value function when `!isset($data[$key]['lesson_'.$lid])`?

Comment: @PatrykRadziszewski oh I thought it's a great problem !!! it worked thanks. please reply to the question and let me choose it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `var_dump($data)` in your value function when `!isset($data[$key]['lesson_'.$lid])` and check what's wrong with your data

Comment: I should say the better answer is to use (isset($x) ? $x : '-')

Comment: @pooria sure, I agree that's it's how it should look in the end... But in certain circumstances we'd like to know what exactly is wrong, especially while developing.

Answer (score 2):

You should check for value is empty or not using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

Use `isset()` inside value function to check for empty value.

For example,

```
(isset($data[$key]['lesson_'.$lid]) ? $data[$key]['lesson_'.$lid] : '-';
```

You can also use `var_dump($data)`.